# Troubles changing objects inside LinkedList

Tags: java, list

```
public static List<double[]> pc = new LinkedList();

public void fillTable1() {
    int index = getWorstI();
    double[] temp = pc.get(index);
    for(int n=0;n<4;n++)
    System.out.println( temp[n]);

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
       (pc.get(i))[j]/=temp[j]; // values change only in object pc.get(1)!  O_o


    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        Main.fillTheRow(table1, pc.get(i), i);

}
```

Comment: You should check the content of (pc.get(i))[j].

Comment: checked. table is filled with values as without division and ony first row is like it should be

Comment: Update your question adding the checked content.

Comment: Is it only pc.get(0) not but pc.get(1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is assumed to be only pc.get(0) that the value is correctly changed.

The variable temp and pc.get(0) is reference to same object.
So the results of "(pc.get(0))[j]/=temp[j]" will be all "1".
Therefor all the calculations after that become (pc.get(i))[j]/1 .

Change as follows not to become a reference.

```
double[] temp = new double[pc.get(index).length]; // new array
for(int n=0;n<4;n++) {
    temp[n] = pc.get(index)[n]; // copy content
    System.out.println(temp[n]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that your problem is somewhere else.  I can see no reason why `(pc.get(i))[j]/=temp[j];` would only work for `i == 1`.  Perhaps there is a problem in the way you populate the `pc` list, or the way youo are reading it.

Comment: If the arrays are identical except for index == 1, then this should be the expected behaviour.

Comment: I have no idea what can the matter  be.... i can only see that division doesn't take effect. Tried also without list - using just arrays of doubles. same thing

Comment: Erik, i didn't catch what you mean

Comment: @Ilya - you are going to have to post the code that populates `pc` and the code (and output) that makes you conclude that division isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the problem lies there?

Try printing the pc before and after the modification to see if it contains what you were actually expecting to be in pc;

Quick convenience method:

```
public static void printList(List<double[]> list)
{
   for (double[] arr : list)
   {
      // import java.util.Arrays;
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
   }
}
```